# Несколько OnTriggerExit за кадр

Tags: c#, unity3d

За один кадр триггер должны покидать несколько объектов и удаляться из пула, но OnTriggerExit отрабатывает один объект из десятка.

Comment: а вы с помощью чего двигаете объекты, которые должны выходить из триггера?

Answer (score 1):

Всё оказалось намного прозаичнее. У меня в одном скрипте объект регистрировался, добавлялся в пул и удалялся из пула при покидании триггера. И удалялся, как раз, последний зарегистрированный, так как удалял  его той же переменной, что и добавлял... невнимательность))

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/302477)

Comment: @DmitryKozlov, где ты видишь дополнение вопроса в этом ответе?

Comment: @Qwertiy "Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для **исчерпывающих** ответов на вопросы". Тут и в вопросе нет примера, да и ответ из серии "А, мой косяк".

Comment: Мда... не все правила усвоил.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, часть объектов успевает проскочить между тактами физики. Попробуйте переставить у 
 объектов в Rigidbody параметр Collision Detection с Discrete на Continuous Dynamic. Это плохое с точки зрения производительности решение, но если заработает - будете знать где искать проблему.